# jboss 7 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, jboss

salem,

I work with jboss 7 , spring ,hibernate,

under eclipse I make this config in order to increase the memory :

**-Xms1024M**

this is the config of VM arguments

```
-server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:/test/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log/boot.log" "-Dlogging.configuration=file:/C:/test/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties" "-Djboss.home.dir=C:/test/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final" -Xms1024M
```

and when I work in my application I have this error :

I have a message which repeats :

**11:08:35,098 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'**

```
11:08:35,098 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,109 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,129 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,136 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,143 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,182 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,193 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,197 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,215 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,224 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,234 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,242 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,264 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,272 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,300 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:35,360 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'

11:08:37,182 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:37,216 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:37,293 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:37,416 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'
11:08:39,309 ERROR [org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No converter found for 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'

11:08:58,234 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/TaifLicensing].[dwr-invoker]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet dwr-invoker a généré une exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:224) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at org.directwebremoting.extend.ArrayOutboundVariable.getAssignCode(ArrayOutboundVariable.java:101) [dwr.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.extend.ScriptBufferUtil.createOutput(ScriptBufferUtil.java:95) [dwr.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler$CallScriptConduit.addScript(BaseCallHandler.java:485) [dwr.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.marshallOutbound(BaseCallHandler.java:345) [dwr.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.handle(BaseCallHandler.java:105) [dwr.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:120) [dwr.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:141) [dwr.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
```

Comment: You've defined `-Xms64m` and `-Xms1024m`, which of these is correct? The second is also larger than `-Xmx512m`, which doesn't make sense. `-Xmx` is the maximum heap size, `-Xms` is the initial heap size. So you're potentially saying that the initial heap size should be twice the size of the maximum heap size.

Comment: Remove multiple occurrences of -Xms, and try  -Xms512m -Xmx1028m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to retrieve an object with a circular relationship, that's why you are getting so many `JavassistLazyInitializer` exception messages. Hibernate will just continue going in circles trying to create your nested objects until you run out of heap space.